# How to display 40 windows with around a hundred animated objects each in Qt Quick?

Tags: performance, qt, opengl, qt5, qtquick2

We are attempting to display 40 windows, each containing almost the same UI, but displaying a different entity, with scene changes with animations happening every few seconds on each window. All of our tests have ended with the windows being drawn at 3 to 5 frames per second at between 10 and 20 windows open, on a reasonably old and low-powered discrete nVidia GPU and on Windows.
Things we have tried:

1. Disabling animations - performance improves, but not nearly enough
2. CPU profiling - shows over 90% of the CPU time being spent in the system DLLs and the nVidia driver; on other machines, the CPU usage is not significant, but the frame rate is still low.
3. QML profiling - The QT Creator profiling shows the render loop executing its steps at 60 fps and within a couple of milliseconds at most for each frame.
4. Images/textures are loaded once to the GPU and never reloaded
5. All the rendering backends - OpenGL, ANGLE and Qt Quick 2D Renderer - perform more or less the same

Is there something major we are missing?

Comment: What kind of effect are you trying to achieve? There may be better solutions than 40 windows * 100 animations... (Creating a new window is a fairly expensive operation and loading discrete images even more so. Remember than to be displayed an image has to be expanded in memory to `total_bytes = height_in_pixels  x  width_in_pixels  x 4` where 4 is the color depth of the image. i.e. 32 bits)

Comment: Displaying 40 different games with the players' actions (which happen a few seconds apart) animating a couple of the one hundred objects.

Comment: Hmm. Is this a game server? If so, my first instinct would be to scale this horizontally and spread the load among several machines.

Comment: It's actually a game client, the servers hopefully will never need to render anything :-)

Comment: But why the *40 windows*?

Comment: @peppe, that's a great question :-) We are porting an existing application that uses separate windows, so that's part of the current business requirements; we will, however, consider switching to laying out a couple of windows with the content of all 40 games